# MSAccess error : No Value given for a required parameter when trying to join more than 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

My query to MS Access is as follows:

```
SELECT po.[PONumber] AS [Purchase Invoice Number]
    , po.[PODate] AS [Purchase Date]
    ,po.PODeposit AS [Purchse Deposit]
    , po.PORemarks AS [Remarks]
    , pitem.PQuantity AS [Quantity]
    , pitem.PPricePerUnit AS [Price Per Unit]
    , pitem.PAmount AS [Amount Paid]
    ,  pclient.PClientName AS [Client]
    , pclient.PClientName.PTel AS [Telephone]
    , pclient.PAddress AS [Address]  
FROM ((PurchaseOrderInvoice AS  po
INNER JOIN PItemDetails AS pitem  ON po.POInvoiceId = pitem.fk_POId)
INNER JOIN PClients AS pclient ON pitem.fk_PClientId = pclient.PClientId)
```

which throws an error like "No value given for one or more required parameters."
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possibly one of your field names does not exist and access thinks it is a variable. If you post your table structure, it will be possible to duplicate and assist further.

Comment: Have you still the same error if you remove the parentheses?

Comment: hi all, i got the answer, actually there was a mistake in Telephone wherein i was mistakenly quering as "pclient.PClientName.PTel" where as it should have been "pclient.PTel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, actually there was a mistake in Telephone wherein i was mistakenly quering as "pclient.PClientName.PTel" where as it should have been "pclient.PTel".